# onToped JFrame opens JDialog = dialog not ontoped over JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

Well, if we have onToped `JFrame`

```
this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

and then open `JDialog`

```
private void colorChooseMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    ColorDialog fc = new ColorDialog();
    fc.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    fc.setModal(true);
    fc.setVisible(true);
}
```

in this case `JDialog` will be 'under' `JFrame`. When I click to frame, dialog moved to top. If I close dialog (dispose on close) and open again it start working normally and showed over `JFrame`

What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ColorDialog should have the jFrame as parent.